# Multiple dynamic divs with forms in jsp and redering the response in corresponding div

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

I placed code of 5 jsps into a single jsp using divs.

I have a jsp which is divided into two main divs left and right. Left div contains the links to the divs of right (contains5). Whenever we click on link (left) corresponding link will be displayed in the right and all remaining divs will be hidden. Each and every div in the right has struts2 form, 2 form contains dropdown list, dependable dropdown list which will prepopulate before coming to our jsp.

If click link1 (assume) corresponding div should be displayed, whenever we submit the form, only that div containing the form should be submitted to server and response should be send back to that div only.

I am displaying the divs using jquery-show() function.

How can we render the response in the same div?

```
<div id="desc-customer" align="center" style="display: none" >

    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
        <s:actionerror />
    </s:if>
    <s:form id="customerFormID" action="createcustomerAction" theme="simple" cssClass="yform" method="execute">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>customer</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Add customer </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <sj:div class="type-text">
                        <td><label for="customerName">customer Name: </label></td>
                        <td><s:textfield name="customerName" id="customerNameId" /></td>
                    </sj:div>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <sj:div class="type-text">
                        <td><label for="label">Label: </label></td>
                        <td><s:textfield name="label" id="labelId"/></td>
                    </sj:div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <s:div class="type-button">
                            <s:submit id="customerFormID"
                                value="Add"
                                targets="msg"
                                indicator="indicator" 
                                button="true" />
                            <img id="indicator" src="../images/indicator.gif"
                                alt="Loading..." style="display: none" />
                        </s:div><%--  <sj:submit value="Create"/> --%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </s:form>
</div>
```